# How to get JDK installer for windows with source code?

Tags: java, java-7

I need JDK installer with  all source files (.java files). So that I can navigate through each classes available in JDK. For this, which JDK installer I should use? 
I am working in windows 7 - 64 bit OS.

Comment: If you take a look in the installation location of the JDK, there is a zip file called `src.zip`

Comment: Yes, I could see that. What I need is, when using eclipse IDE, I should be able to navigate to each class from eclipse by clicking Ctrl+Click.

Comment: Normally I would link the `src.zip` to my project and simply browse through it. Not sure if/how this is done in Eclipse.  Maybe try changing your question to reflect this need

Comment: @Shibu for eclipse try changing installed JRE path in >>windows>>prefrence>>java>>Installed Jre. It must be pointing to intalled JRE location. Remove it and add new which points to installed JDK

Answer (score 1):

When you download JDK(not the JRE) you should have the sources(src.zip) in the same compressed file(Normally it's .zip for Windows.)

[image: JDK 1.6]

Comment: Thanks for answering. How can I access it from eclipse itself? .java files should be opened by Ctrl+MouseClick on class names.

Comment: You need to attach sources. Generally you can do this using settings but when you do Ctrl+MouseClick on class names you should see just the functions which are picked up from .class files. Same time a small dialog will appear on the UI saying attach sources. Click on it and rest will be self explanatory.